# What are valid chunks extensions?

Tags: http, chunked-encoding, chunks

[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) defines chunked encoding and states :

> The chunked encoding allows each chunk to include zero or more chunk
> extensions, immediately following the chunk-size, for the sake of
> supplying per-chunk metadata (such as a signature or hash),
> mid-message control information, or randomization of message body
> size.

But I can't find a list of these extensions, would someone know where to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chunk extensions are not pre-defined. You add custom extensions per your  implementation requirements.

Here is the quote from Wikipedia on how to format it:

> If chunk extensions are provided, the chunk size is terminated by a
>   semicolon and followed by the parameters, each also delimited by
>   semicolons. Each parameter is encoded as an extension name followed by
>   an optional equal sign and value. These parameters could be used for a
>   running message digest or digital signature, or to indicate an
>   estimated transfer progress, for instance.

Url to Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: Thanks. I must have misread the RFC 7230 because section 4.1.1 also talk about it : "The chunked encoding is specific to each connection and is likely to
   be removed or recoded by each recipient (including intermediaries)
   before any higher-level application would have a chance to inspect
   the extensions.  Hence, use of chunk extensions is generally limited    to specialized HTTP services such as "long polling" (where client and
   server can have shared expectations regarding the use of chunk
   extensions) or for padding within an end-to-end secured connection."

Comment: Yeah, what I understood from that segment was that basically anything in between the server: proxy, firewall, load balancer, etc... most likely won't respect your chunk extensions by passing them along so they'll get lost before they ever reach the client.